# Puma clustering benefits for site which handles lots of uploads/downloads

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, puma

I'm trying to understand the benefits of using puma clustering. The GitHub says that the number puma workers should be set to the number of cpu cores, and the default number of threads for each is 0-16. The worker processes can run in parallel while the threads run concurrently. It was my understanding that The MRI GIL only allows one thread across all cores to run Ruby code, so how does puma enable things to run in parallel /provide benefits over running one worker process with double the amount of threads? The site I'm working on is heavily IO bound, handling several uploads and downloads at the same time - any config suggestions for this set up are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workers in clustered mode will actually spawn new child processes each of which has its own "GIL". Only one thread in a single process can be running code at one time, thus having a process per cpu core works well because each cpu can only be doing one thing at a time. It also makes sense to run multiple threads per process because if a thread is waiting for IO it will allow another thread to execute.